# PhpDoc: protected property

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is it possible to declare `protected` or `private` class @property using PhpDoc?

```php
/**
  * Class Node
  * @package app\models
  * @property string $name
  */
class Node
{

}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but why to tell, that class has some property, that can't be accessed?

Comment: you might want to document internal magic methods/properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. For `@property`, `public` is implied, even if it's read-only or write-only. The point of such tags is about documenting interfaces that can't be inferred. A private/protected variable is really internal to the class so it's only relevant to child classes which should be written as if they already know this. You can still leave a plain docblock immediately before you declare it, though.

Comment: If there's some reason to highlight a magic property that's not actually public, you can use the `@internal` tag to explain why that property deserves to be highlighted.